# Eevee motion blur do different utility to objects?

Tags: animation, eevee-render-engine

I built my scene with .abc animation and still assets, and I opened motion blur in scene setting.
As you could see that the garments part have more motion blur than the head.
Why is that happening and how to fix this?
[image]

[image]

Comment: I’m not sure, but I do know that motion blur in EEVEE works only with camera motion: It is a screen space effect. If the head and scenery are moving with the camera, but the body isn’t, that might happen…

Comment: @ZargulTheWizard Sence it is an blur algorithm based on vertexes transformation within screen scope, all objects should be blured using that standard and capable to be expected. Apparently my character has his garment body and head moves forward together at the same pace, I really can't figure out what's going on about that motion blur.

Comment: you know more about it than me I guess. Yeah, that is weird.